# Is it possible to have two different colors of text in one cell with NPOI?

Tags: c#, excel, fonts, npoi

I am using NPOI to export a `DataTable` as a spreadsheet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _instance.ResultsData.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = sheet.CreateRow(i + 1);

    for (var j = 0; j < _instance.ResultsData.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(_instance.ResultsData.Rows[i][_instance.ResultsData.Columns[j].ToString()].ToString());
    }
}
```

For a certain column, I would like to have two different colors of text.  Essentially, in the following string:

```
abc|123|xyz
```

I would like the pipe characters to be a different color than the actual text in between.  Is this possible to do with NPOI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  The key is to use an `IRichTextString` when setting the cell value.  This object has an `ApplyFont` method which accepts a `startIndex`, `endIndex` and an `IFont`.  You can create a font having the alternate color you want, then apply that to the pipe characters within the cell value.  Here's how:

1. First, create a font for the alternate color.  You only need to do this once, so put this code somewhere before your loops.

   ```
   IFont redFont = workbook.CreateFont();
   redFont.Color = HSSFColor.Red.Index;
   ```
2. Create a method which will create the `IRichTextString` and apply the font to the pipe characters.  Note: If your workbook is an `HSSFWorkbook`, use `HSSFRichTextString` instead of `XSSFRichTextString`.

   ```
   static IRichTextString ApplyColorToPipeChars(string value, IFont font)
   {
       var richString = new XSSFRichTextString(value);
       for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
       {
           if (value[i] == '|')
           {
               var j = i + 1;
               while (j < value.Length && value[j] == '|') j++;
               richString.ApplyFont(i, j, font);
               i = j;
           }
       }
       return richString;
   }
   ```
3. In your loop that creates cells, call the `ApplyColorToPipeChars` method as needed and set the cell value from that:

   ```
   DataTable table = _instance.ResultsData;
   for (var i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(i + 1);

       for (var j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
       {
           ICell cell = row.CreateCell(j);
           string value = table.Rows[i][j].ToString();

           if (shouldApplyColorToCellValue)  // change this condition to suit your needs
               cell.SetCellValue(ApplyColorToPipeChars(value, redFont));
           else
               cell.SetCellValue(value);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but your exact method is not working even though I can see the expected code flow when debugging.  I am creating the font like this : var redFont = (XSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
            redFont.FontHeightInPoints = 12;
            redFont.IsBold = false;
            redFont.Color = IndexedColors.Red.Index;

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong either; it works for me.  What is the condition that you are using in place of `shouldApplyColorToCellValue`?  Is that branch being taken?  Are you writing the changes to the xlsx file?  Maybe you can include a [mre] in your question so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The condition is really just "is it column 1".  I know the method is being entered and that line executed, i also tried the SetColor method to no avail.  I'll mess with this a bit more.  Thank you for your help, I will likely post a MRE soon.